# Atribuir variável de ambiente Linux no python

Tags: python

Preciso ler uma variável de ambiente no Linux, e armazenar em uma variável no Python. Ja tentei de várias formas e não obtive sucesso.

Eu iniciei com este comando, no linux `$variavel='123123'`

```
x = os.system('echo $variavel')

print('{}'.format(x))  #~~> que resulta em 0
```

mas com pesquisas descobri que ele basicamente vai dizer que o comando deu certo ou não.

Qual o comando para que eu possa armazenar o valor da variável e utilizá-la no código depois? Já li a documentação da biblioteca `os`, mas ainda sim estou tendo dificuldades, alguém poderia me dar uma força?

Answer (score 1):

O módulo `os` possui um dicionário com as variáveis de ambiente que pode ser acessado por [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ). Se o seu ambiente possui a variável `PATH` e você deseja acessá-la via Python basta fazer:

```
import os
PATH = os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: ficou perfeito, eu havia tentado com essa opção, mas o erro estava na variável de ambiente do Linux mesmo... Obrigado!